# Why does radio button not function on mobile?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I built an online interview. The form uses Angular.js and Bootstrap to display questions and answers. Each answer is attached to a point value that gets summed and totaled at the end for a test score.

The application works wonderfully on Chrome and Safari (both desktop apps), and in Chrome Dev Tools, it simulates well on a multitude of mobile screens.  However, when I view the app on an actual mobile device, I am unable to select an answer among the radio buttons.  What can I do to debug?

Is Angular.js likely the cause?  Perhaps this is a known problem with Bootstrap?  How do I troubleshoot and repair?

Live Site (works on desktop currently (April 7,2016), but not on mobile):
http://libertas-security466.info/interview

test.html (Template for each question/answer set)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>{{question.text}}</h1>
            <p ng-show="question.subtext">{{question.subtext}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p>Remaining Questions: {{questionsLeft}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" ng-model="selectedAnswer" value="{{answer.text}}" ng-click="setCurrentAnswer(answer)">
                        </div>
                        <label class="form-control">
                            {{answer.text}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9 text-center">
            <button ng-click="answer(currentAnswer)" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Select Answer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FreemasonTest">
    <head>
        <title>Are you ready?</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/routes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/model/AssessmentModel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/questions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/needs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/controllers/TestController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/controllers/ResultsController.js"></script>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Libertas-Security Lodge #466</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On mobile it looks like the buttons are disabled - http://imgur.com/PGxyCS4

Comment: I can't see a reason for the issue, if you've got android you can debug like so - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Comment: The radios were not actually disabled, but you helped me to find the true problem. Thank you!

Comment: There are answers like this, try see: -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927406/angular-6-proxy-not-working-anymore -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681813/angular-proxy-config-not-working

Comment: @RiccardoGangi, I appreciate your input, but the answers that you link were posted 2 years after I found the answer I needed. Please check to see if a question has already been answered before posting additional help. ;)  Stay awesome.

Comment: [Sidenote] One can always use a select box / list box to **replace** a radio button set. (in iOS sometimes we call such similar thing as a picker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@KieranDotCo provided the direction I needed. The solution to this problem comes in two parts:

1. How do I trouble shoot?
2. What is wrong?

== Troubleshooting ==

The instructions found at [developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/…](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en#remote-debugging-on-android-with-chrome-devtools) provided everything I needed to find and track down the solution.

== Making the App Work ==

The problem was not with Angular.js.  Neither was it technically with Bootstrap, but the Bootstrap CSS was causing the problem.

I let the default column definition define the button div for the XS screen dimensions. In the Chrome debugger (image below), we will see that the `<div>` that contained the `<button>` element to select an answer, had dimensions that placed it **above** my radio buttons.  This means that every time I tried to click a radio button, the blank space surrounding the "Select Answer" button was grabbing my event and bubbling it around the radio buttons to the body element that lay behind them.

[image]

In the above image, we see that when we select the `<div>` element which should cover the button and only the button that we have a highlighted area that expands in front of the radio buttons.

The answer to the problem lay in changing the class of this div to specify behavior for XS screens.  After I add "col-xs-12" to the button div, the div no longer sits in front of the radio buttons and I can select options as I need to.

[image]

In the above image, we highlight the `<div>` as before, but now we see that the div is not bigger than the line that holds the `<button>`. The "col-xs-12" class 'fixed' the `<div>` dimensions and thus the app.

== Thank You ==
Big thank you to @KieranDotCo for teaching me about this great feature of Google Chrome's desktop application.  You have opened a whole new world of debugging for me!

Comment: No problem :) Thank you for posting a detailed answer of how you solved the problem!

Comment: That was my problem exactly.  Thank you very much, Mr. Lister and Jared!