# Angular migration (from 4 to 6) e2e --proxy-config not working

Tags: angular, protractor, angular6, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I've been currently migrating my app from 4 to 6 and I can not executing my proxy script **for my e2e tests**.

The script listing looks as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:tst1": "ng serve --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst1.json",
    "start:tst5": "ng serve --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst5.json",
    ...
    "test:watch": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check true",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:tst1": "ng e2e --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst1.json",
    "e2e:tst5": "ng e2e --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst5.json",
  },
```

What I don't understand is, that the **start commands (ng serve)** work perfectly fine for instance`npm run start:tst5`. But when I try to execute the e2e tests like `npm run e2e:tst5` it throws me the error: `Unknown option: '--proxyConfig'`.

The config in my **angular.json** looks as follows:

### angular.json

```
...
"lmsbo-bo-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e",
  "sourceRoot": "e2e",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "lmsbo-bo:serve"
      },
        "configurations": {
            "production": {
                "devServerTarget": "lmsbo-bo:serve:production"
            }
        }
    },
  ...
```

## Edit

I got the e2e test working with following addition in the `angular.cli`:

```
        "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
                "browserTarget": "lmsbo-bo:build",
                "proxyConfig": "config/proxy/proxy.tst5.json" <== **added this** line
            },
            "configurations": {
                "production": {
                    "browserTarget": "lmsbo-bo:build:production"
                }
            }
        },
```

But this solution approach is not satisfying by any means. I got to change this line of code every time I want to execute against another environment. I would rather want to manage this via command line by writing something like: `ng serve --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst5.json`.

Comment: Try see this:
-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681813/angular-proxy-config-not-working -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927406/angular-6-proxy-not-working-anymore bye

Comment: Not what I am looking for.

Comment: You can run the following command in terminal before your test execution

Set the proxy in terminal 

    SET https_proxy=http://yourcompanydomain.com:portnumber
    SET http_proxy=http://yourcompanydomain.com:com:portnumber

Comment: The proxy configuration is already set. When i execute `ng serve --proxy-config config/proxy/proxy.tst1.json` it works all fine. But when i replace `serve` with `e2e` the error appears. Im kind of frustrated....

Comment: From what I can see, it is not supported anymore
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11408   
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6358

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much what I suspect right now. Is it maybe possible to add multiple paths in the `proxyConfig: ....` and then execute different paths via ng serve `---proxyOptions=...` ?

Comment: there is an open issue for this on GitHub see following https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6358

Comment: @creep-story can you pls share `config/proxy/proxy.tst5.json` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though this feature is not supported anymore and there is already an open issue on github, Ive found out a pretty convinient way to execute the proxy config via `script`:

add in your package.json following lines (example):

```
"e2e:local": "ng config projects.**yourAppName**.architect.serve.options.proxyConfig **yourProxyFile1** && ng e2e && ng config projects.**yourAppName**.architect.serve.options.proxyConfig ''",
"e2e:tst1": "ng config config projects.**yourAppName**.architect.serve.options.proxyConfig **yourProxyFile2** && ng e2e && ng config projects.**yourAppName**.architect.serve.options.proxyConfig ''"
```

All you do is to set the `proxyConfig` value in your `angular.json` via `ng` command and reset it after the e2e tests are finished. Make sure the `ng` command is working (if not add your `angular/cli` path into your environment properties of your operating System and restart your computer).

Comment: This will throw me `Error: Unexpected end of file.` when it tries to remove config.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by updating your angular.json as follows (substitute your project name for my-project):

1) In projects -> my-project-e2e, update devServerTarget from

```
"my-project:serve"
```

to

```
"my-project:serve:e2e"
```

2) In projects -> my-project -> architect -> configurations, add

```
"e2e": {
          "browserTarget": "cli-advisor-portal:build:e2e",
          "proxyConfig": "proxy.local.config.json"
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. It worked very well for me - in my case I wanted to use two different proxy configs for two different environments (local and test).

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly - you want to avoid having to change the proxy config line every time you want to run e2e tests against different evironment:

Create separate proxy configs for your environments such as:

- `proxy.config.yourenv1.json`
- `proxy.config.yourenv2.json`

Add configurations for each environment under `serve`:

`"serve": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "yourenv1-e2e": {
              "browserTarget": "yourapp:build",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.yourenv1.json"
            },
            "yourenv2-e2e": {
              "browserTarget": "yourapp:build",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.yourenv2.json"
            }
          }
        },`

Then under yourapp-e2e again add configurations for each environment:

```
"yourapp-e2e": {
  ...
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      ...
      "configurations": {
        "yourenv1-e2e": {
          "devServerTarget": "yourapp:serve:yourenv1-e2e"
        },
        "yourenv2-e2e": {
          "devServerTarget": "yourapp:serve:yourenv2-e2e"
        },
      }
    },
```

Now you can simply run this:

`ng e2e --configuration yourenv-e2e`

The e2e tests will run using desired proxy config file.
**Based on the @raymondboswel's answer.**