# angular proxy config not working

Tags: angular, npm

i don't understand where i am wrong .

ps. already try to fix by this answer but still not working

[Angular-CLI proxy to backend doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809008/angular-cli-proxy-to-backend-doesnt-work)

[Configure Angular-cli proxy for custom headers in request to backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872498/configure-angular-cli-proxy-for-custom-headers-in-request-to-backend)

[Angular-CLI proxy doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616755/angular-cli-proxy-doesnt-work)

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  
http://localhost:1234
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "budget",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:1234",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Angular CLI: 6.1.2

Node: 10.8.0

OS: darwin x64

Angular: 6.1.1

npm -v 6.2.0

Answer (score 4):

You're matching only `/api` url. If you want to match urls that begin with `/api` but have something else use `/api/*`.

#### proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1234",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

### Explanation

This configuration will proxy from local-server (lets suppose it is `localhost:4200`) to your target, so:

- `localhost:4200/api` --> `http://localhost:1234/api`
- `localhost:4200/api/product` --> `http://localhost:1234/api/product`
- `localhost:4200` --> no proxy
- `localhost:4200/whatever` --> no proxy

If you want to exclude `/api/` from the target route, include `pathRewrite` inside in `proxy.config.json`:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1234",
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:1234",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

to

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:1234",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
"pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```